# Unable to change value to element dynamically in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

When I am running this code a runtime Exception is thrown by Compiler,

```
String ExistUser = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='**UserBody']/tr[j]**/td[1]")).getText();
```

while when I changed j into 1, I get the output

```
String ExistUser = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id=**'UserBody']/tr[1]**/td[1]")).getText();
```

but I am unable to understand why it happens, can anyone please help me.

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UserBody']/tr[1]/td[1]") ).size()!= 0)
{
   int j;
   for (j=1 ; j< 10; j++)
       {
         String ExistUser = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='UserBody']/tr[j]/td[1]")).getText();
         //String value = ExistUser.getAttribute("value");
         System.out.println(ExistUser);

       }
}
```

Comment: dude..u r using variable. y dnt u correct ur code

Comment: @nitinchawda yup...i gt it...nd thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
 if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UserBody']/tr[1]/td[1]") ).size()!= 0)
      {
         int j;
     for (j=1 ; j< 10; j++)
     {
         String ExistUser = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='UserBody']/tr["+j+"]/td[1]")).getText();
         //String value = ExistUser.getAttribute("value");
         System.out.println(ExistUser);

     }
      }
```

When ever you want to mention a variable, need to place '+' symbol also.

&

And remove the '.' before XPATH, I think it's not a good habit.

Comment: @ShivaRoy Welcome. If you found solution, accept the answer. So that others also can know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are putting in the literal string `j` as opposed to the contents of the `j` variable.

Something like this will work:

```
String ExistUser = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='UserBody']/tr[" + j + "]/td[1]")).getText();
```